# Shiny renderDataTable table_cell_clicked

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to create a table using Shiny, where the user can click on a row in order to see further information about that row.  I thought I understood how to do this (see code attached).

However, right now as soon as the user clicks the "getQueue" action button, the observeEvent(input$fileList_cell_clicked, {}) seems to get called.  Why would this be called before the user even has the chance to click on a row?  Is it also called when the table is generated?  Is there any way around this?

I need to replace "output$devel <- renderText("cell_clicked_called")" with code that will have all sorts of errors if there isn't an actual cell to refer to.

Thank you for any advice!

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   actionButton("getQueue", "Get list of queued files"),
   verbatimTextOutput("devel"),
   DT::dataTableOutput("fileList")     
)

shinyServer <- function(input, output) {
   observeEvent(input$getQueue, {
   #get list of excel files
   toTable <<- data.frame("queueFiles" = list.files("queue/", pattern = "*.xlsx")) #need to catch if there are no files in queue
   output$fileList <- DT::renderDataTable({
     toTable
   }, selection = 'single') #, selection = list(mode = 'single', selected = as.character(1))
   })
   observeEvent(input$fileList_cell_clicked, {
     output$devel <- renderText("cell_clicked_called")
   })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = shinyServer)
```

[minimal error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrFsy.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DT` initializes `input$tableId_cell_clicked` as an empty list, which causes `observeEvent` to trigger since `observeEvent` only ignores `NULL` values by default. You can stop the reactive expression when this list is empty by inserting something like `req(length(input$tableId_cell_clicked) > 0)`.

Here's a slightly modified version of your example that demonstrates this.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("getQueue", "Get list of queued files"),
  verbatimTextOutput("devel"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("fileList")     
)

shinyServer <- function(input, output) {

  tbl <- eventReactive(input$getQueue, {
    mtcars
  })

  output$fileList <- DT::renderDataTable({
    tbl()
  }, selection = 'single')

  output$devel <- renderPrint({
    req(length(input$fileList_cell_clicked) > 0)
    input$fileList_cell_clicked
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = shinyServer)
```