# Shiny: renderPrint() show additional info stored in table basing on input$id_cell_clicked

Tags: r, shiny, dt

My shiny App displays a table of available datasets basing on two inputs (Subgroup and Type). Below this table I would like to print additional info of a selected row (basically because showing all rows in one table makes the table output chaotic). I found a similar question on this website ([Shiny renderDataTable table_cell_clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47371525/shiny-renderdatatable-table-cell-clicked)), which worked fine. However, the rendered print contains only info of the selected cell ($row, $col and $value), but I would like to print infos of the selected row which is stored in the same dataset in col 11 to 17.

I think the problem is that my output$Availabledatasets filters the dataset and afterwards the object is not available. I tried different things but none helped out. I'm new to shiny and DT (as well as stackoverflow) but I think the solution is pretty straightforward and I am missing something  basic. Sorry for any inconvenience and I would really really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

minimum code example:

```
dataset <- read.xlsx("data/data.xlsx", sep.names = " ") 

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "Subgroup",
                label = "Choose a Subgroup",
                choices = unique(dataset$Subgroup)),
    uiOutput("secondSelection")
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "Availabledatasets"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "info"))

#built server side function
server <- function(input, output){
  output$Availabledatasets <- renderDT({
    filtered <- dataset %>% filter(Subgroup == input$Subgroup,
                                   Type == input$Type) 
    datatable(filtered[1:10], selection = "single")
  })
  output$secondSelection <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Type", "Choose a Type", 
                choices = dataset[dataset$Subgroup == input$Subgroup, "Type"])
  })
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    req(length(input$Availabledatasets_cell_clicked)  > 0)
    input$Availabledatasets_cell_clicked #here I would like to display column 11 to 17 of my selected dataset 
  })
}
    

app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

runApp(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your dataset using the information provided by `input$Availabledatasets_cell_clicked$row`, and the column indices can be hardcoded.

```
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    req(length(input$Availabledatasets_cell_clicked) > 0)
    dataset[input$Availabledatasets_cell_clicked$row, 11:17] 
  })
```

I made a reproducible example with using `mpg` dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

# create data
writexl::write_xlsx(mpg, "dat.xlsx")
dataset <- readxl::read_xlsx("dat.xlsx")
file.remove("dat.xlsx")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "Subgroup",
      label = "Choose a Subgroup",
      choices = unique(dataset$manufacturer)
    ),
    uiOutput("secondSelection")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "Availabledatasets"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "info")
  )
)

# built server side function
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Availabledatasets <- renderDT({
    req(input$Subgroup)
    req(input$Type)
    filtered <- dataset %>% filter(
      manufacturer == input$Subgroup,
      class == input$Type
    )
    datatable(filtered, selection = "single")
  })
  output$secondSelection <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Type", "Choose a Type",
      choices = dataset[dataset$manufacturer == input$Subgroup, "class"]
    )
  })
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    req(length(input$Availabledatasets_cell_clicked) > 0)
    dataset[input$Availabledatasets_cell_clicked$row, 3:10] # here I would like to display column 11 to 17 of my selected dataset
  })

}


app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

runApp(app)
```

[image]